# Replacing \ with \\ and " with \" before assigning to a string

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I have few lines of input as

```
"callbackProxy({"7103/usatoday/high_impact/entertainment/main":{"_type_":"html","_expandable_":false,"_html_":"\x3chtml\x3e\x3chead\x3e\x3cstyle\x3e\x3c!--\na:link { color: #000000 }a:visited { color: #000000 }a:hover { color: #000000 }a:active { color: #000000 } --\x3e\x3c/style\x3e\x3cscript\x3e\x3c!--\n(function(){var d\x3d{};window.ss\x3dfunction(a){void 0!\x3d\x3dd[a]?d[a]++:d[a]\x3d1;var e\x3ddocument.getElementById(a),b\x3dd[a];if(window.css)css(a,\x22nm\x22,b,void 0,void 0)"
```

I need to replace the `\x` with `\\x` and `"` with `\"` before assigning it to a string. since just `\x` gives error and `"` in between a string also gives error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you are heading in the right direction. Can you explain where the input comes from and what you want to do with it in the end?

Comment: Do you just need to escape it in order to hard-code it into your program? You could probably just google "string escaper" and find some online utility to do it for you.

Comment: The input is a .js(Javascript) file with all kinds of encoding both URL and hexcode.I need to convert it into proper JS where \x3c gets converted < and so does all % url encodings.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused. Can't you just process it like a normal reg ex?

Comment: Are you just copy-pasting this String from js file to Java code?

Comment: Yes I am copy pasting it.

Comment: Are you copy-pasting entire content of file or just fragment?

Comment: There is no need to replace single by double backslashes unless you are writing either source code or a Properties file. You need to reconsider this.

Comment: But I am getting the right output.Its just that I have to manually replace \ with \\ and " with \"

Comment: You wouldn't have to escape it if you read contend of your file using Java code like for example: `Files.readAllLines(Path path, Charset cs);` from `java.nio.file` added in Java7, or `FileUtils.readFileToString(File file)` from `org.apache.commons.io`. In case you don't want to use Java code you can use something like http://www.htmlescape.net/javaescape_tool.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are just copying and pasting this, you need to perform the following substitutions:

- `\x` to `\u00`
- `"` to `\"`
- `\u0022` to `\"`

(Note that the last one is not a very normal requirement, but your example code contains `\x22` which would be translated to `\u0022` which is not allowed in Java string literals)

[For the first you can replace matches of the regex `\\x` with `\u00`.](http://regex101.com/r/yH9oX2)

[The second two can be accomplished with a single regex by replacing matches of `"|\\u0022` with `\"`.](http://regex101.com/r/fC4pV7)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line like this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\"|(\\\\x)", "\\$0");
```

Answer (score -1):

let's assume that string is in variable x

```
x = x.replace("\\x","\\\\x");
x = x.replace("\"","\\\"");
```

That should do the trick

Comment: But x is not valid right on assignmnet since it has \ only and not \\

Comment: Even if `x` was valid this wouldn't work, since to represent \ literal you need to use \\\\ in Java regex.